# Swift 3: How to use action button in multiple sections of a table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, swift3

I'm trying to run a unique function when a button is clicked in each row of each section. 
The problem for example is, if i have 3 rows in 3 sections and i configure the first row to run a function when the button is pressed, the first row for all 3 sections runs the same function. I'm trying to achieve running unique functions for all rows in different sections.

This is my `tableView` code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: languageID, for: indexPath) as! LanguageTableViewCell

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.phraseLBL.text = "description 1"
        cell.playBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.playBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PhraseVC.pressPlay), for: .touchUpInside)

    case 1:
        cell.phraseLBL.text = "description 2"
        cell.playBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.playBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PhraseVC.pressPlay), for: .touchUpInside)

    case 2:
        cell.phraseLBL.text = "description 3"
        cell.playBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.playBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PhraseVC.pressPlay), for: .touchUpInside)
    default:
        break
    }

    return cell
}
```

And this is the `IBAction` of `Button`:

```
@IBAction func pressPlay(sender: UIButton){

        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            print("button 1 pressed")

        case 1:
            print("button 2 pressed")

        case 2:
            print("button 3 pressed")

        case 3:
            print("button 4 pressed")

        case 4:
            print("button 5 pressed")
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do like

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: languageID, for: indexPath) as! LanguageTableViewCell
    
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.phraseLBL.text = "description 1"
        
        
    case 1:
        cell.phraseLBL.text = "description 2"
        
    case 2:
        cell.phraseLBL.text = "description 3"
       
    default:
        break
    }
    
    cell.playBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.playBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PhraseVC.pressPlay(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
  
    
    return cell
}
```

and call the method as

```
@IBAction func pressPlay(_ sender: UIButton){
    
    let touchPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:maintable)
    // maintable --> replace your tableview name
    
    let clickedButtonIndexPath = mainTable(forRowAtPoint: touchPoint)
    
   
    
}
```

For Latest Swift Versions :

```
 @IBAction func pressPlay(_ sender: UIButton){
    let touchPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
    // tableView --> replace your tableview name
    if let clickedButtonIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
        print("Section : \(clickedButtonIndexPath.section) , Row:  \(clickedButtonIndexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set to each cell an Index Path and not tag. `IndexPath` consists of section and row. By checking to which section and which row the button belongs you can uniquely identify the correct function.